# Telerik Grid MVC not displaying data on read

Tags: telerik, asp.net-core-mvc, telerik-grid

So I've got a grid that I believe is all set up correctly. I've confirmed that the data is coming through, and I've even checked that the AJAX call returns a success with the "ToDataSourceResult" JSON data.

​

Unfortunately, the only problem is that the data doesn't display. This seems to only be an issue on read, as update, create and delete all work. Just can't retrieve the list of all items afterwards.

​

My controller action looks like this:

```
public IActionResult Blog_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var blogs = _blogService.GetPosts().Select(post => new BlogPostModel
            {
                Id = post.Id,
                Title = post.Title,
                Author = post.Author,
                ShortDescription = post.ShortDescription,
                Contents = post.Contents,
                LastSaved = post.LastSaved,
                Published = post.Published,
                PublishedOn = post.PublishedOn
            });
            var result = blogs.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(result);
        }
```

​

And my Grid View looks like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BlogPostModel>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.Title);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Author).Width(120);
                columns.Bound(p => p.LastSaved).Width(120);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Published).Width(120);
                columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(250);
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable()
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style= "height:600px;"})
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)
                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                .Create(update => update.Action("Blog_Create", "BlogAdmin"))
                .Read(read => read.Action("Blog_Read", "BlogAdmin"))
                .Update(update => update.Action("Blog_Update", "BlogAdmin"))
                .Destroy(update => update.Action("Blog_Delete", "BlogAdmin"))
            )
            .Deferred()
        )
```

​

The correct JSON is returned, no javascript errors in the console, so I'm a little confused as to what this could be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

to my Startup.cs ConfigureServices method.